# Making Carbon in Graphite accept all data, no matter what

Tags: graphite

The Carbon listener in Graphite has been designed and tuned to make it somewhat predictable in its load on your server, to avoid flooding the server itself with IO wait or skyrocketing the system load overall.  It will drop incoming data if necessary, putting server load as the priority.  After all, for the typical data being stored, it's no big deal.

I appreciate all that.  However, I am trying to ***prime a large backlog of data*** into graphite, from a different source, instead of pumping in live data as it happens.  I have a reliable data source from a third party that comes to me in bulk, once/day.

So in this case, ***I don't want any data values dropped on the floor***.  I don't really care how long the data import takes.  I just want to disable all the safety mechanisms, let carbon do its thing, and know ALL my data has made it in.

I'm searching the docs and finding all kinds of advice on tuning the parameters of carbon_cache in carbon.conf, but I can't find this.  It is starting to sound more like art than science.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: This includes creating thousands of .wsp files, on this initial load.  Things should get easier after that.  Regardless, I just want to import my data reliably, no matter what.

Comment: which version on graphite do you use ? (0.9.x or master?)

Comment: Version 0.9.12-5.el6 as seems to be the current version in EPEL for CentOS 6.

Comment: So as I understand it, carbon_cache listens via TCP for data.  (I'm avoiding any UDP option.)  Starting from scratch, it starts creating whisper.wsp files at up to MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE and writing data to them at up to MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND.  When that's exceeded, it starts caching updates in RAM, up to MAX_CACHE_SIZE as measured in data points (not bytes).  When that cache is full, if USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True, it starts pausing and not accepting data over your socket until there is room in the cache, again.  But if USE_FLOW_CONTROL = False, it drops data on the floor.

Comment: IF that above logic flow is true, then it does NOT work as designed, at least in Version 0.9.12-5.el6.  USE_FLOW_CONTROL does not work.  I also hit a bug where the whole carbon daemon crashed with a Python exception when my overall data exceeded ~2GB and ~3,000 .wsp files.  Now I guess I need to start hunting version notes and see if an upgrade would help all of this.  As anyone using Graphite knows, it balances on a house of cards, starting from your version of Python all the way up to Django and its mile-long list of pre-requisites.

Comment: Here is what I saved from the crash.  No my file system was not full.  Maybe I ran out of inodes, although that seems unlikely.  I can't check right now. 

`teCachedDataPoints()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/carbon/writer.py", line 121, in writeCachedDataPoints
    settings.WHISPER_FALLOCATE_CREATE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/whisper.py", line 386, in create
    fallocate(fh, headerSize, remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/whisper.py", line 66, in _py_fallocate
    raise IOError(res, 'fallocate')
except[root@centos6-testdmz01 carbon]#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing of course is to receive data through tcp listener (line receiver) instead of udp to avoid loosing incoming points.

There are several settings in graphite that throttle part of the pipeline, though it is not always clear of what graphite does when threshold are reached. You'll have to test and/or read the carbon code.

You'll probably want to tune:

`MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND = 500` (max number of disk updates in a second)

`MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE = 50` (max number of metric creation per minute)

For the cache, `USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True` and `MAX_CACHE_SIZE = inf` (inf is a good value so revert to this if you changed it)

If you use a relay and/or aggregator, `MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10000` and `USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True` are important.

Comment: Yes one of the best comments they could put in carbon.conf would be to explain that MAX_CACHE_SIZE is not bytes.  I am using a simple default setup, all on one very plain VM, with one carbon_cache daemon.  UDP is disabled.  I've started graphing the queue size, and it varies from 0 to about 50k data points.

Comment: I'm using the Perl Net::Graphite module for the data input.  I'm guessing it's not smart enough to honor flow control with the carbon cache daemon?  Is that the underlying problem?  I am doing pretty well with Time::HiRes and some micro-sleeps in perl to keep from overflowing carbon.  Without that, though, carbon drops 90% of my data on the floor, regardless of all these settings.  I have left "USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True" as default.

Comment: A lot of people view this question but there hasn't been much discussion on it. Hopefully carbon has matured in the past 3 years. I can also suggest running it on bare metal because of the high disk I/O requirement. It's likely here the problem stemmed from slow VM disk. I have also seen USE_FLOW_CONTROL actually work since then, but I don't have details to post. If anyone still sees this issue (dropped data) please speak up.

Answer (score 1):

I set this property to "inf":

MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE = inf

and make sure that this is infinite too:

MAX_CACHE_SIZE = inf

During the bulk load, I monitor /opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/creates.log to make sure that the whisper DBs are being created.
To make sure, you can run the load a second time and there should be no further creations.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this works on a reasonably well-powered server. A big problem, in my case, was that I was on a test virtual server with very slow disk access. I knew that was a rough test case but I thought carbon should still handle it properly. I started with "inf" like you suggest, but that was a disaster on that VM if I recall.

Comment: This answer does help see if, at least, you have entire .wsp files being skipped/dropped during a fast import. Particular data points inside .wsp could still be suspect. One could script-scan the .wsp files for NULL values in the given time period. -If you know your incoming data + carbon settings well enough.